# Getting singleton instance inside its methods

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I've got simple singleton class:

```
class Singleton
{
    public:
        static Singleton& getInstance()
        {
            static Singleton instance;
            return instance;
        }
        // private constructor, etc...
}
```

The question is how should I access class instance from its member functions?
I've seen various code snippets and now I'm curious whether they have any significant differences.

1.

```
void Singleton::something(){
    Singleton &self = getInstance();
    self.doSomething();
}
```

2.

```
void Singleton::something(){
    this->doSomething();
}
```

3.

```
void Singleton::something(){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: No there aren't any significant differences between those dereferencing methods.

Comment: What is the reason for making the class a singleton?

Comment: @immibis this class is settings manager and I need only one instance of it.

Comment: @gmlt.A It's OK to have only a single instance of a class, but that doesn't automatically qualify to make it a singleton. You can pass a reference to the single instance around, to where it's actually needed.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ So you are telling me I should create SettingsManager (which I should rewrite to exclude singleton behavior) object and pass its reference to different parts of my code to store\get config values? There will be additional arguments is this realy better than one singleton class?

Comment: @gmlt.A _"is this realy better than one singleton class? "_ Yes, it's better, because your code will be less tightly coupled. Think about passing around interfaces, which will make that code better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is unnecessary complication - in a non-static member function like `something` we already have an instance, so there is no need to get it separately.
2. and 3. are the same, only 3. is shorter and more idiomatic - using `this->` to access a member in C++ is not common.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be any other member function to get class instance except `Singleton::getInstance();`, because this is why it exist. Do it as below:

```
Sungleton &dst=Singleton::getInstance();
```

In fact, no way to get instance from non-static member function. When there is no class instance , how can you call its non-static member.